# ObjectContext.SaveChanges with BackgroundWorker

Tags: wpf, entity-framework, backgroundworker

I have problem with ObjectContext.SaveChanges method:

```
  public void Save(Action<object, object> action)
    {
        EventAggregator.GetEvent<EntityServiceRequestingEvent>().Publish(true);
        var bw = new BackgroundWorker();
        var saved = false;
        bw.DoWork += (o, ee) =>
                         {
                             ProgramStatusService.Status = Resources.DatabaseSavingMessage;


                             if (!CanSave())
                             {
                                 throw new InvalidOperationException(
                                     "You must not call Save when CanSave returns false.");
                             }
                             try
                             {
                                 lock (Context)
                                 {
                                     Context.SaveChanges();
                                     saved = true;    
                                 }
                             }
                             catch (ValidationException e)
                             {
                                 MessageService.ShowError(null, string.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture,
                                                                              Resources.SaveErrorInvalidEntities,
                                                                              e.Message));
                             }
                             catch (UpdateException e)
                             {
                                 var innerException = e.InnerException as SqlException;
                                 if (innerException != null && innerException.Number == 2601)
                                 {
                                     MessageService.ShowError(null, string.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture,
                                                                                  Resources.DublicateKeyUpdateError,
                                                                                  e.InnerException.Message));
                                 }
                                 else
                                 {
                                     MessageService.ShowError(null, string.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture,
                                                                                  Resources.SaveErrorInvalidFields,
                                                                                  e.InnerException.Message));
                                 }
                             }
                             ee.Result = saved;
                         };
        bw.RunWorkerCompleted += (o, e) =>
                                     {
                                         EventAggregator.GetEvent<EntityServiceRequestingEvent>().Publish(false);
                                         ProgramStatusService.Status = Resources.ProgramReadyMessage;
                                         if (e.Result != null) action.Invoke(this, e.Result);
                                     };
        bw.RunWorkerAsync();
    }
```

While saving i'm getting error: **The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.** in Designer.cs:

```
   /// <summary>
    /// No Metadata Documentation available.
    /// </summary>
    [EdmScalarPropertyAttribute(EntityKeyProperty=false, IsNullable=true)]
    [DataMemberAttribute()]
    public Nullable<global::System.DateTime> MDate
    {
        get
        {
            return _MDate;
        }
        set
        {
            OnMDateChanging(value);
            ReportPropertyChanging("MDate");
            _MDate = StructuralObject.SetValidValue(value);
     ReportPropertyChanged("MDate");// **ERROR HERE**

            OnMDateChanged();
        }
    }
```

How to properly use ObjectContext with BackgroundWorker?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only correct way to use context in background worker is to create it in `DoWork` handler, use it and dispose it before `DoWork` handler ends. `ObjectContext` is not thread safe and locking it for `SaveChanges` will not change it.

The exception you are receiving is not caused by EF but by WPF and UI controls. You cannot modify control from non-UI thread. You must use Dispatcher to work with controls.